# Typescript set object with another array of objects

Tags: typescript

How to achieve this with typescript.

```
interface PostResponse {
  name: string
  value: null | string | number
}

interface Post {
  title: string
  user_id: number | null
}

// imagine we are getting some API response
const response: PostResponse[] = [
  { name: 'title', value: 'abc' },
  { name: 'user_id', value: 123 },
]

// we want to set this data from response
const data: Post = {
  title: '',
  user_id: null
}

function setData(response: PostResponse[]) {
  for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    const { name, value } = response[i]

    // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Post'. ts:7053
    // No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Post'.
    data[name] = value
  }
}

setData(response)
```

getting this error at here  "data[name] = value"

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Post'. ts:7053
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Post'.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NdrjvW) work for your use cases?  You need to use the technique in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) for the compiler to see the correlation between the `name` and `value` properties of a `PostResponse` (I changed the name `Response` because there's an existing global interface with that name, and because it only works for `Post` objects anyway).  If that is okay I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes, it's working. i really thankful to you for solving my issue.

but type is look like little complex.

can you share me the docs guide or some post about it.

i just want to understand this concept for the other related problems.

Thanks Again!

Comment: I've posted an answer explaining as much as I can, with links to related issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that your `PostResponse` definition

```
interface PostResponse {
  name: string 
  value: null | string | number
}
```

isn't specific enough to guarantee that `data[name] = value` is a safe operation.  First, you allow `name` to be any `string` whatsoever, even ones which are not keys of `Post`:

```
const oops: PostResponse = {
  name: "randomName", // no error
  value: 123
};
```

Oops. We can address that by constraining `name` to the keys of `Post` by using [the `keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator):

```
interface PostResponse {
  name: keyof Post
  value: null | string | number
}
```

That will prevent completely random `name` values.  But there's still no *correaltion* between the types of `name` and `value`:

```
const oops: PostResponse = {
  name: "title",
  value: 123 // no error, but this should be a string, not a number
}
```

Oops again.  Really, your `PostResponse` type should be a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the two `name`/`value` type pairs you want to accept.  You can make the compiler compute this from `Post` via a *distributive object type*, as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Essentially you build a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) into which you [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with a union of all the keys, to get a union of all the values.  That could look like this:

```
type PostResponse = {
  [P in keyof Post]: { name: P, value: Post[P] }
}[keyof Post]
```

which evaluates to:

```
/* type PostResponse = {
  name: "title";
  value: string;
} | {
  name: "user_id";
  value: number | null;
} */
```

You can see that `PostResponse` must either have a `"title"`-valued `name` and a `string`-valued `value`, *or* it must have a `"user_id"`-valued `name` and a `number | null`-valued `value`.  The possibility of "cross-correlated" terms has been eliminated:

```
const oops: PostResponse = {
  name: "title",
  value: 123
} // error!
```

So now we finally have a `PostResponse` type that represents your constraints.  It will even automatically update itself if you update `Post`.  But unfortunately, your `setData()` still has an error:

```
function setData(response: PostResponse[]) {
  for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    const { name, value } = response[i]
    data[name] = value // error!
    // Type 'string | number | null' is not assignable to type 'never'
  }
}
```

Why?

---

The problem is that TypeScript doesn't really represent *correlated unions* very well.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for more information.  While the compiler "understands" that a `PostResponse` cannot have cross-correlated `name` and `value` properties, it only understands that if you [narrow on the `name` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) explicitly:

```
    if (name === "title") {
      data[name] = value; // okay, name is "title", value is string
    } else {
      data[name] = value; // okay, name is "user_id", value is number | null
    }
```

If you try to write that as a single line, `data[name]=value`, the compiler is confused.  It sees that `name` is `"title" | "user_id"` and `value` is `string | number | null` and then worries about the possibility of `{name: "title", value: 123}` even though that's impossible.

So that's why.  What can be done?

---

An approach that works is detailed in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Instead of using unions, we use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) that are [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the union, so that the `data[name]=value` operation is seen as setting a value of type `Post[K]` to a property of type `Post[K]` for a generic type parameter `K extends keyof Post`.

Here's how we can write it:

First we slightly redefine the `PostResponse` distributive object type so that it takes an optional `K` type parameter which [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `keyof Post`:

```
type PostResponse<K extends keyof Post = keyof Post> =
  { [P in K]: { name: P, value: Post[P] } }[K]
```

If you just write `PostResponse` you get the same union type as before, but now you can narrow to just the union member corresponding to `K`; for example:

```
type PostTitleResponse = PostResponse<"title">;
/* type PostTitleResponse = {
    name: "title";
    value: string;
} */
```

Now, the following generic function will compile with no error:

```
function setOne<K extends keyof Post>(response: PostResponse<K>) {
  const { name, value } = response;
  // const name: K extends keyof Post
  // const value: Post[K]
  data[name] = value; // okay
}
```

And thus your original `setData()` can be written like this:

```
function setData(response: PostResponse[]) {
  for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    setOne(response[i]); // okay
  }
}
```

Note that you can't just use generics inline without a function scope, so trying to rewrite the above without `setOne()` would need to involve an anonymous generic callback, which is weird:

```
function setData(response: PostResponse[]) {
  for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    (<K extends keyof Post>(response: PostResponse<K>) => {
      const { name, value } = response;
      data[name] = value
    })(response[i]);
  }
}
```

It's more conventional to use callbacks with [the array `forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of a  regular [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```
function setData(response: PostResponse[]) {
  response.forEach(<K extends keyof Post>(response: PostResponse<K>) => {
    const { name, value } = response;
    data[name] = value; //okay
  });
}
```

So that's probably how I'd leave it.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4Ch8klRJYFkVhkDjiNgAXCNAMwqQAUB7KRgJWgxuwKDSJ1ipCAC4kfTMCwTJANxAAbAK6ySWjRqQAfeY0U4TwLWABGLFUgC+hSfBF8k3bjChyefQVh3ZABePAcpcF0AIjQQYAATbjAAOSjogBokAHpskm4kFjRuNAikdW1dAEYAJgBmB0cAbglnCWlyRCQAFQB3Ato6BmY2Dn8BIWDwyUjIOQBrCABPblYuXkYyip05KwNjU3MDq1t7STbXd0ZPb191gMnRUOmZ6TloxgxGDQhMrc0dkhag1zq0XCQop1kN0ABZoCDiByMJYwZDjQLCJ5IMKDSQAbU4SAYSEWKzW4wAunJcBC5lwsttdOMCRSnI08aTVvdGBTwcRsgAqJDI1HcjFTHFlN5ID5fH7RFozcoA3QKBhYRV0RwHXF0aXRLRiNAAfQwCQV-0qu2sdjQx30Gk1xG1AuyfKQblE1y8Pj8G3FWMlSv1n2+vwylsBwMaOTyRRKAEJCA5WFpgPBPiJ5BBGAARECMEAACnhQSefoeZbEeIpAEoXpJWCUkEWftcMNikAAGJpEpAAHiQpcxYgAdD8lIwYb2MABqWf13WXL14WkQBkqpyd4fBPEYXlK4gJAsgPHSVlhRmxwpoYpoJOH6-dFHIADkaqU9tOdssDtfRKgfJrhAKAoGwUAbB+YUChFN9qFUFhXzKZxQRTNMMwwLMxDzE8ahLR4xArCYqwgGtFzKJs7VbHM+zCHs+0HHcnnHCBJ2nIl53Ix9PQ8GlpA3SotzCJjq33Mp6DWItpGxEIwllMNoi4x8kGPQszyiC9lUqJ0Zm1CANDEBtD1U09z07RkdNBJUUK1ZMwUINphhYdgunGF5Qx+OQP2UYhDRYU0Emtb97QMfA2lgsUCIgfsAGlCgAD2YRJAM5ckNk7VLuQAPmxCQaQJIlgCQGKqVXaVOAEwFmU4VltUcPESsICLxm6OUIADQywnRKL+3k+UspaQVhRfblWrDDrnl1EM2otNQVS8sx1RaF03XwXIiTAEAsAYZBemQEB4SQLAc0+T8oGSZAAEFOAASSHKL8B464RKZf0oprTs8Tytc5FfDyIFfSrdFfEAbHgf9HAjYg+KiX6-JNM1Aa0qN6icCNeTWvI9qQXp4muRgCmw4UYQwQCTKQVhijAe6SMeq4VJPIjO0Gf7fsBiR4YC61QraVN00zIrsKoaK4ogRLWISFLli5cYsvwkiiIm2KsqUp6yqiIGhJpkcIE1da1elUXxeSklpbSvgJH1+nGSIhqDwZtSzMvFVe3W7h5hAJYwuTPmMKwnN80LAANeWdcV966xeSiWzbWjuxnAdteCFi2JnTijKF6hQ93fda01ZxefQgXsxwwsAE1s-LSKSLIqPm2o9tO3ojtGKilOsCnNOFyMotYoSpLJdNslssrwjq515X6xCHKlw9emYcgTXtWEqLLId0yNPMlVGlrUfSNz-PvfwX3i+wwPixe8Oa8jwYXtHSiAFEEBhXujYHqXh9lver4nmKVexGeDg1YL3XMjZAy8k5PB0iZdSkBNKMlaHnI+Z8Tx7yQXTUQ3Afjjm4FgIsJkkFDUGH1X47xQbwD+MQA0RoArRDkNGFaQA)

Comment: Props for a very detailed and well explained answer :) #goals